# Raspbian LXDE Separate Wallpaper for each Workspace/desktop

Tags: lxde

As seen [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/30056/raspberry-pi-raspbian-multiple-desktops/30057?noredirect=1#comment40875_30057) it is possible to create multiple desktops/workspaces with LXDE desktop environment. However, I would like to also have a separate wallpaper for each desktop. I could not find anything in my searches about this and did not see any options in the GUI. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click **Menu**
2. Select **Preferences**
3. Select **Desktop Preferences**
4. Choose whatever wallpaper selection
5. Uncheck **Use the same wallpaper on all desktops**