# Automatic Cycling Of Virtual Desktops

Tags: raspbian

Is there a way to automate cycling thought the virtual desktops as a specific interval?   I have Raspbian currently installed but am not against the possibility of using another OS if required

I would like to use a PI3 as a log / graph monitoring system connected to a large display at my office which will cycle though several browsers that are running, one on each desktop. This is possible to do with Dexpot on Windows but i would like to use the PI3 if this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something I've done before, so this may land wide of the mark.

SteveRobillard's answer [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/30057/32756) says that the shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+[left/right]`will cycle through desktops. The task then becomes automating keypresses in LXDE. I *think* you can achieve that using [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/). Cobbling together a couple of examples leads me to something that probably looks a bit like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    xdotool key ctrl+alt+Right
    sleep 10
done
```

That's completely untested I'm afraid. It *should* infinitely loop around the xdotool command to bump the desktop to the next one, then wait 10 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply.  Will test Monday and post my results.   Have a great weekend